# How do I print out the lowest number that uses a string array in python?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, compare, min

I am trying to get the lowRain function to print out the lowest number in the array with the month as well. 
For example when I run through the loop in the rainInput function and enter these numbers(4, 3, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 8, 23, 10), it will go through the lowRain function. When I try to return the month that yielded the lowest rain I get "The lowest rainfall for December was 10 inches."

```
def main():
  rainfall = rainInput()
  low, lowMonth = lowRain(rainfall)
  print("The lowest rainfall for " + str(low) + " was " + str(lowMonth) + " inches.")


def rainInput():
  rainfall = ["January", "Febuary", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
  for month in range(len(rainfall)):
    rainfall[month] = (int(input("Please enter the amount of rain for " + str(rainfall[month]) + " :")))  
  return rainfall

def lowRain(rainfall):
  month = ['January','Febuary','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December']
  lowMonth = min(month)
  print(lowMonth)
  for m, n in enumerate(rainfall):
    if lowMonth:
      lowMonth = n
      low = m
  return month[low], lowMonth


main()
```

Comment: why not use a dictionary?

Comment: To get the most out of Stackoverflowit is important to [ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), that includes creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Comment: what is `rainfall`? post some example of `lowRain` call

Comment: Can you please give an example of how `rainfall` looks like.

Comment: This is an ok example, but you should replace the input with a static array

Comment: How would you be able to get the input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `lowMonth = min(month)` on the array of month names that you defined 1 line before that, which would always result in `April`. I'm guessing that you wanted to check which month has the minimum rainfall that was inputted before, in which case you could do this:

```
def lowRain(rainfall):
    lowest = min(rainfall)
    index_of_lowest = rainfall.index(lowest)
    month = ['January','Febuary','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December']
    lowest_month = month[index_of_lowest]
    return lowest_month, lowest
```

Comment: Thanks, you answered my question.

Answer (score 0):

If you keep the rainfall amount and month names together then you can use the `min` function:

```
>>> data
[(4, 'January'),
 (3, 'Febuary'),
 (10, 'March'),
 (10, 'April'),
 (10, 'May'),
 (10, 'June'),
 (10, 'July'),
 (10, 'August'),
 (10, 'September'),
 (8, 'October'),
 (23, 'November'),
 (10, 'December')]

>>> min(data)
(3, 'Febuary')
```

This is because when `min` compares sequences it compares the sequence components in order, in this case first the rainfall amount and then the month name. The result will always have a minimal rainfall amount, and if there are multiple months with the same minimal rainfall you'll get the month that comes first in an alphabetical sorting.